# Matrix manipulation in Octave

Tags: matrix, octave

I want to map a `mX1` matrix `X` into `mXp` matrix `Y` where each row in the new matrix is as follows:

```
Y = [ X X.^2 X.^3 ..... X.^p]
```

I tried to use the following code:

```
Y = zeros(m, p);
for i=1:m
    Y(i,:) = X(i);
     for c=2:p
    Y(i,:) = [Y(i,:) X(i).^p];
    end
end
```

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want do is called brodcasting. If you are using Octave 3.8 or later, the following will work fine:

```
octave> X = (1:5)'
X =

   1
   2
   3
   4
   5

octave> P = (1:5)
P =

   1   2   3   4   5

octave> X .^ P
ans =

      1      1      1      1      1
      2      4      8     16     32
      3      9     27     81    243
      4     16     64    256   1024
      5     25    125    625   3125
```

The important thing to note is how X and P are a column and row vector respectively. See the [octave manual on the topic.](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html)

For older of versions of Octave (without automatic broadcasting), the same can be accomplished with `bsxfun (@power, X, P)`

Comment: Thanks. It's working. Anyway I made it in another way. `for i=1:numel(X)

 Y(i,:) = [X(i,:) X(i).^(j=2:p)] ;
 
end
`

Comment: @Niyas yeah, you can write a for loop like you did but that's much slower, less memory efficient, and less readable. If you are not using Octave 3.8 or later, then you can use `bsxfun (@power, X, P)`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the uglier `bsxfun` syntax is required if the code is to be made MATLAB-compatible.  At least until Mathworks implements operator broadcasting in the same way that Octave is doing.  :)